# Does anyone know how to set MSEDGE Canary homepage set up Android

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have been searching all day and I cannot for the life of me find out what the url is for Microsoft Edge! I'm trying to set it as my homepage on my Samsung S20, but it says it needs a url, but whenever I go to search for the url, it just tells me about MS Edge Canary/Chrome doesn't use urls anymore. I don't have a windows version, and the only other information I can find is for Windows phones! I have a MS365 account, so I am also running into sync problems between Edge, Edge Canary, Edge Canary Dev, as well as Bing, Google, and Google Chrome. If anyone could possibly let me know if there's another way of accessing Edge, specifically Canary, as their homepage, I would be so grateful!

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Is my answer below helpful to deal with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know how to set the browser homepage in MS Edge? If this is the case, you could refer to these steps below:

1. Launch Microsoft Edge on Android.
2. Tap on **...** menu for options.
3. Choose the **Settings** menu from the list.
4. Select the **Home page** tab from the available menu options.
5. Switch the Radio button to **A Specific page**.
6. Enter the URL that you want to set as a homepage. ex: https://www.bing.com
7. Hit on the **Save** button.

If I misunderstood anything, could you explain what the "what the url is for Microsoft Edge" you mentioned is? And describe your problem in more detail? Thank you for your understanding.